# Is it possible to execute a shellcode that's placed on stack?

Tags: windows, stack, reverse-engineering, control-flow, shellcode

Is it possible to execute a shellcode that's placed on stack? I am using Windows. (It probably won't change the fact but maybe some other rules exist on different operating systems.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stacks in Windows are protected with [data execution prevention (DEP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/data-execution-prevention), so you can't execute any instructions on stack.
This was possible with older Windows versions, that didn't support DEP.

Comment: And probably ROP technique comes from that. Really cool.

Comment: Yes, DEP uses NX bit.